# Formula for Finding Text in a Text String and Returning Adjacent Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have an odd problem that I could use an expert's eye for. Basically I have a normal contact datasheet with First, Last, Title etc, and another excel file with a text string and corresponding location that contains the text in the datasheet. I want to add this location to the contact file.

So, I've added a Firstname+lastname column and I'm trying to reconcile the text string and corresponding location with the other contact information.

I need a formula that will search the name of the contact in Column C in the text string in column D and return the corresponding location in column F.

See picture of how I have the data now.

I've use a variety of formulas with VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH but with no luck. The need for it to find the text in a string makes this tricky. After Hours of searching I haven't found something similar.

Here's a link to an example of the data:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

In F1

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH("*"&C1&"*",D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy it down.
The formula will return a blank if a match is not found.